# How can I fit the center item in owl carousal 2 after using transforming: scale(2.0) on it without being cropped vertically

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap card and owl carousal 2, when using `transform: scale(2.0)` on the center item, it gets cropped vertically instead of being centered, it is being overflowed in the owl-stage part. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Here are my codes:

HTML:

```html
<div id="cars-news" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/lexus.jpg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Picture 4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title text-center">لورين ابوسو</p>
        <p class="card-text text-center">لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوم</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/lexus.jpg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Picture 4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title text-center">لورين ابوسو</p>
        <p class="card-text text-center">لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوم</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/lexus.jpg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Picture 4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title text-center">لورين ابوسو</p>
        <p class="card-text text-center">لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوم</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/lexus.jpg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Picture 4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title text-center">لورين ابوسو</p>
        <p class="card-text text-center">لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوم</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/lexus.jpg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Picture 4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title text-center">لورين ابوسو</p>
        <p class="card-text text-center">لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوم لورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوملورین ابوسوم</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#cars-news .owl-item.active.center {
  filter: blur();
  transform: scale(2.0);
  display: block !important;
}

#cars-news .center .card:before {
  content: none;
  transition: 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

#cars-news .owl-item.active {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#cars-news .owl-item {
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

#cars-news .owl-item.active.card {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.card-title {
  color: #217187;
}

#cars-news .owl-stage-outer {
  transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}

#cars-news .owl-item.card img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Jquery:

```js
var owlnews = $('#cars-news').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
nav: true,
margin: 100,
dots: true,
center: true,
navText: ['<span class="left-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-4x"></i></span>', '<span class="right-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x"></i></span>'],
responsiveClass: true,
responsive: {
    0: {
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
    },
    600: {
        items: 3,
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
    },
    1500: {
        items: 3,
        loop: true,
        dots: true,
    }
}
});
});
```

This is currently the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rakxn.png)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xB41.png) is what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

What if try another way?
All items except the central one - reduce by 4 times `transform: scale (0.25)`
And central item only - set height what you need.